# Print current time for 10 times with an interval of 10 seconds in python

Tags: python, datetime

This prints current time, for 10 sec interval what function or loop I have to use

```
import time;
    
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
print "Local current time :", localtime
```

Comment: use `time.sleep(10)`

Answer (score 2):

You should argoment better the question!

By the way if tou are trying to print every 10 seconds the current time for 10 times you can do it as:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime


#For 10 times
for x in range(10):
  # Get current time
  now = datetime.now()
  # Make a string of it
  current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  # Print it
  print(current_time)

  # Wait for 10 seconds
  time.sleep(10)
```

Output:

```
14:33:33
14:33:43
14:33:53
14:34:03
14:34:13
14:34:23
14:34:33
14:34:43
14:34:53
14:35:03
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the `time.sleep()` method along with a loop that iterates 10 times `for i in range(10)`

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
    print ("Local current time :", localtime)
    time.sleep(10)
```

a bit more advanced with proof that it works

```
import time

interval = 10
logged = []
for i in range(10):
    localtime = time.localtime(time.time()).tm_sec
    print ("Local current time :", localtime)
    logged.append(int(localtime))
    time.sleep(interval)

print(len([i for i in range(1,len(logged)) if logged[i-1] + interval == logged[i]])+1 == len(logged))
```

```
Local current time : 43
Local current time : 53
Local current time : 3
Local current time : 13
Local current time : 23
Local current time : 33
Local current time : 43
Local current time : 53
Local current time : 3
Local current time : 13
True
```

Comment: no problem! if you liked the answer you can click the green checkmark to accept it for future users. Thanks for asking!